# Issue with react-hook-form useController when using it with tabs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I have tried multiple times to make this work but unfortunately I am with no luck. I am trying to submit a form in 4 steps divided by tabs:

so I have my initial state:

```
const initialValues = {
  step1: {
    statement: '',
    weight: '',
    statements: [],
  },
  step2: {
    statement: '',
    weight: '',
    statements: [],
  },
  step3: {
    statement: '',
    weight: '',
    statements: [],
  },
};
```

I then initialize a the form like so:

```
const Form = () => {
  const methods = useForm({ defaultValues: initialValues });

  const onSubmit = () => {
    methods.handleSubmit((data) => console.log('data: ', data));
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <FormProvider {...methods}>
        <section>
          <TabContent
            tabsList={Object.keys(assetTypes).map((assetType) => assetType)}
            defaultTab="tab1"
          >
            {(activeTab) => {
              console.log('rendering for: ', activeTab);
              return <Feature tabName={activeTab} />;
            }}
          </TabContent>
        </section>
      </FormProvider>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

I then create the TabContents so that I can finally write data to the form state:

```
import React, { memo, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useController } from 'react-hook-form';

const Feature = ({ tabName }) => {
  console.log('rendering tab', tabName); --> changes just fime
  const {
    field: { value, onChange: fieldOnChange },
  } = useController({ name: tabName });

  const onChangeStatement = (e) =>
    fieldOnChange({
      ...value,
      statement: e.target.value,
    });

  const onChangeWeight = (e) =>
    fieldOnChange({
      ...value,
      weight: e.target.value,
    });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('tabName: ', tabName); <--- that changes correctly
    console.log('value: ', value); <--- always points to the first state tab1
  }, [tabName, value]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>{tabName}</h1>
      <input onChange={onChangeStatement} value={value.tab1?.statement} />
      <input onChange={onChangeWeight} value={value.tab2?.weight} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default memo(Feature);
```

Hoewever, whenever I switch tabs the state does not point to the tab I am in. Here's a live demo if you want to check it out: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5dpii4

I would reallly appreciate if someone could help me

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `tabName` prop to `useForm` hook so that it can track the current tab.

Comment: I don't understand. You mean having tabName on the defaultValues? Why do I need to track tabName if I am already doing that in the component and calling `const {
    field: { value, onChange: fieldOnChange },
  } = useController({ name: tabName });` with the correct name? Please take a look at the stackblitz, you will see it better in there